# rails using "or" in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a logic problem that I haven't been able to figure out.

I'm trying to count inspection `tasks` that are done.

The following in task.rb works fine:

```
def self.done
  where("rating_id is not null").where("taskterm_id is not null").where("esthours is not null").where("estmat is not null").where("estenddate is not null")
end
```

If any of the 5 fields are null, then the task is not done.

But, I would also like to count the task as done if the `rating_id` = 5

So, I tried this:

```
where(:rating_id => 5) or (where("rating_id is not null").where("taskterm_id is not null").where("esthours is not null").where("estmat is not null").where("estenddate is not null"))
end
```

But, it's not setting it to done if the second half of the `or` is true.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` method is defined on ActiveRecord relation. Each call to `where` returns a new relation, so you can call `where` on it again.

When using the relation results, ActiveRecord executes the sql query returned by the relation object and brings you all the results. Hence by calling:

```
where(:rating_id => 5) or ...
```

You are executing the query `SELECT <your_table_name>.* FROM <your_table_name> WHERE <your_table_name>.rating_id >= 5`. This is never falsy (in worst case it will give you an empty array) and whatever is on the right side of `or` is ignored.

Note that you want to make just single sql call. You can do this with:

```
where('rating_id => 5 or (rating_id is not null and taskterm_id is not null and esthours is not null and estmat is not null and estenddate is not null)')
```

Unfortunately earlier versions of rails don't have a good support for not, and none so far have support for custom `or`. You can have a look at Squeel gem to improve the query so it doesn't rely on pure sql: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel

There is also `activerecord_any_of`
 gem: https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of, with which your query could be written as:

```
any_of( where(rating_id: 5), 
        where.not(rating_id: nil, taksterm_id: nil, esthours: nil, estmat: nil, estendate:nil)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where("rating_id = ? OR (rating_id is not null AND taskterm_id is not null AND esthours is not null AND estmat is not null AND estenddate is not null)", 5)
```